Salesforce LWC - Loop Fields in Multiple lightning-record-edit-forms
I have created 4 lighting-record-edit forms on a custom object.  On the click of a button, I want to check each one of the fields.  I need to check if field A is populated that either field B or C is populated. In addition, there is a percentage field on the lightning-record-edit form that I need to make sure the total of all 4 records is not more than 100%
Here is what one of the 4 lighting-record-edit-form's look like  They all have the same exact info except I only have a onSubmit on the first one.
    <!-- Incented Employee #1 Primary-->
    <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Incented_Employees__c" data-id="IeForm" onsubmit={handleSubmit} onsuccess={handleIeSuccess}>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                <div class="slds-size_6-of-12">
                    <lightning-input-field lwc:ref="employee1" field-name="Employee__c" required={ie1IsAccountManager}></lightning-input-field>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-size_3-of-12">
                    <lightning-input-field lwc:ref="type1" field-name="Type__c"></lightning-input-field>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-size_3-of-12">
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="Member_Lock_In__c"></lightning-input-field>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-size_4-of-12">
                        <lightning-input-field lwc:ref="percentage1" field-name="Member_Credit_Percentage__c"></lightning-input-field>
                </div>
            </div>               
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>

Here is my starting point at looping each record edit form, I am struggling to determine how I loop each field in each edit form and do the checks.  Thank you!!
this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-record-edit-form[data-id="IeForm"]')
  .forEach((form) => {
    console.log('here is the form ' + form);
  });


If no iterator wraps your form, the best is to use lwc:ref as the most Salesforce-like way to refer to fields. And you've already started out:
lwc:ref="employee1"
...
lwc:ref="type1"

The fields in the first record-edit form should have a "1" suffix, the fields in the second a "2" etc. This gets us started.
this.refs is not an array, but that doesn't stop us working with its properties as if they were:
Object.keys(this.refs).filter(e => e.startsWith('employee'))
    .forEach(e => console.log(e));

... will output all the keys starting with "employee".
To check field values in B and C depending on A, we can:
// a check function for single record-edit form:
const check = (i) => (
    !this.refs['employee'+i].value 
    || this.refs['type'+i].value || this.refs['member'+i].value);
// check done for 4 record-edit forms
const checkAll = check(1) && check(2) && check(3) && check(4);

To sum up percentages:
const sum = Object.keys(this.refs)
    // only consider percentage fields
    .filter(e => e.startsWith('percentage'))
    // only consider fields with a value (not null, undefined, or empty string)
    .filter(e => this.refs[e].value)
    // sum the values
    .reduce((prev, cur) => prev + parseFloat(this.refs[cur].value), 0);
if(sum > 100) ...

I would do some rounding here, but I leave this to you.
Finally, to answer the question from the comments,

Can I add an lwc:ref to the lightning-record-edit-form, loop through the fields in that form and add them to a list?

lwc:ref can be attached to any element (outside of a lwc iterator), including lightning-record-edit-form. However, any lwc:ref returns Javascript objects of type HTMLElement - just like what the items in the list represent that are returned by querySelectorAll(). Child elements can be accessed by means of standard DOM means, e.g.
this.refs.form2.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field')[3].value

But the lightning-input-field won't exhibit "lwc:ref" as an attribute. The following attempts are dead ends:
// returns 0
this.refs.form2.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field[lwc\\:ref]').length;
// returns undefined
this.refs.form2.refs;

So the answer to the question will be: Yes, this is possible, but inside of the form you'd need to work with standard DOM access, which is in my view less readable and maintainable than the use of lwc:ref.
(It is often pointed out that lwc:ref comes with a significant speed advantage. But because lwc:ref can't be used inside of iterators, there aren't many cases where this matters.)

Thank you. One question.. when I run the first snipet and  do .forEach(e => console.log(e)); , the values in the console are 'employee1 employee2 employee3 employee4 instead of the values that are in the field.. how di I get the values

Are you referring to my first code example with the console.out()? For the value replace e by this.refs[e].value .

yes.  thank you!  I appreciate it!!!

Sorry, one more follow up question.  Can I add an lwc:ref to the lightngin-record-edit-form, loop through the fields in that form and add them to a list?  thanks again!!

Okay, Frank, I've added the answer to this question to the text of my answer :-)
